# Which way do the fade sliders in Skyrim go?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, performance

I've looked around the web before but never clearly understood (and never observed the effects in-game from) these sliders.

What do the "Object Fade", "Grass Fade", "Light Fade" etc sliders *mean*, and which way (to the right, or to the left) does what?

Does putting a slider to the right (filling the bar) increase performance, or increase visual effects?

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

These sliders affect the [**draw distance**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draw_distance) of game objects, grass, and detailed lighting effects. The higher these settings are, the farther from the camera these effects will be visible or drawn at high detail.

Moving the slider to the right increases the draw distance, which enhances visual fidelity at the cost of performance.

This can be adjusted beyond the limits of the sliders by editing the configuration file manually, but this is only recommended for advanced users with high-end hardware.

Comment: Caveat is that this is 2019.  Even integrated graphics card are at least "mid range" relative to Skyrim's release date of 2011.